# php Page and star rating plugin full rendered only after refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using [fyneworks jquery star-rating](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) with jQuery mobile and in one page created dynamically with a PHP function everything is working fine.  But in another page where the "rating tab" is included in the PHP page, the stars are not rendered until I refresh the page.

**PAGE**

```
 <?php
session_start();
if (!session_is_registered('autorizzato')) {
  echo "<h1>Area riservata, accesso negato.</h1>";
  echo "Per effettuare il login clicca <a href='login.php'><font color='blue'>qui</font></a>";
  die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script src='rating/jquery.MetaData.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src='rating/jquery.rating.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <link href='rating/jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="logged.js"></script>
</head>
<body background="#000000">

<div data-role="page"  id="lista">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <input type="submit" onClick="back()" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-left" value="Indietro" />
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <a href="logout.php" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
    <form id="save" action="saveComment.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="textarea">Comment:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
        <label>Rating:</label>
        <div data-role="content" >
                <input data-role="none" name="stars" type="radio" class="star" value="1"/>
                <input data-role="none" name="stars" type="radio" class="star" value="2"/>
                <input data-role="none" name="stars" type="radio" class="star" value="3"/>
                <input data-role="none" name="stars" type="radio" class="star" value="4"/>
                <input data-role="none" name="stars" type="radio" class="star" value="5"/>
        </div> 

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" value="1" />
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Invia">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**logged.js**

```
$(document).load(function () {  
     $('#rt').click(function () {
            var div = $(this);
            div.children('input').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                    $('#rating').attr("value", $(this).val());
                } 
            });
        });

    });
```

I noticed that the page created dynamically by PHP is accessing my database, and takes about 2-3 seconds to display, and everything is rendered.  This second page is rendered only after I press F5 and refresh the page.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is maybe for browser async nature. Second time the data may come from cache so rendered.

Comment: I think the same. Is there a way to prevent it? Both Chrome (desktop) and android browser present the same behaviour.

Comment: What does it show when not loading stars?

Comment: 5 simpel radio buttons. The other thing strange is that the function  $('#rt').click(function () is not triggered! Debugging with chrome, the click event is received only after the page refresh

Comment: Try removing document.load and using $(function(){ //your code here });

Comment: yes with $(function() the script is working fine, but the rating star are not rendered. I posted my website to try live.

Comment: you mean the click function are working now? Sorry, i havn't access to my computer now. I am on journey. But i count the problem and will try to help you soon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27724/discussion-between-silentboy-and-starssky)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried .ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
});
```